# Sending both the value and key of an option box as parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to send both the value and key of the option box when I submit a form.  I feel like this should be pretty simple, but I'm unsure how to do it.  Below is a snippet from my form to demonstrate what I'm referencing:

```
<form name='form' onSubmit="return checkForm();" action="../servlet/AccountRequest">

<select name="type1">
   <option value="1">Option A</option>
   <option value="2">Option B</option>
</select>

<br/><input type="button" id="Submit" onclick="checkForm(this.form)" value="Request" />
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```

​
In a normal scenario, if I selected "Option A" in the drop-down box, I would want to send the value, or "1".  However, I want to actually send the value AND key of the selection, in this case both "1" and "Option A".

In my case, I call a checkForm() JavaScript function that validates form input (there are other fields, like First Name, Last Name, Email Address, and Password), which then forwards the parameters to a Java class (AccountRequest).  I'm sure there is a way to store the key as a variable when the "Request" button is clicked, I just don't know how.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might not be the approach you were expecting, but you could send the key/value pair as your value and parse it when you receive it server-side.

```
<select name="type1">
   <option value="1,Option A">Option A</option>
   <option value="2,Option B">Option B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could play with a jSON representation of your data:

```
<select name="type1">
 <option value="{'1':'Option A'}">Option A</option>
 <option value="{'2':'Option B'}">Option B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

In HTML, this is impossible: the data contributed by a `select` element is *defined* to be the `value` attribute of the selected `option`, when present (otherwise the content of the selected `option` element).

In JavaScript, it would be pretty easy, once you have decided *how* the content (“key” in your description) should be passed. At the simplest, you could append the content to the `value` attribute, with some separator between the strings; then you would have to parse that server-side, but that would be simple too.

However, it is part of the very idea of `option` elements that the content is the visible string in the user interface, understandable to the user, and the `value` attribute is the machine-readable easily processable data. In good design, they are kept as separate, not combined; the server should only need the data from the `value` attribute; otherwise there is a design flaw that should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You could add this code to get the text of your selected `<option>` tag in your `checkform` function:

```
var select = document.getElementsByName("type1")[0]; // get select element - simpler if it has an ID because you can use the getElementById method
var options = select.getElementsByTagName("option"); // get all option tags within the select

for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) { // iterate through all option tags
    if (options[i].value == select.value){ // if this option is selected
        var key = options[i].innerHTML; // store key of selected option here
    }
}
```

[**DEMO, which tells you the key that's selected**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/ZLz8B/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use a compound value, then parse it out on the server:

```
<option value="1_A">Option A</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can send the value with an input type hidden

1.-choose the default value:

```
<input type="hidden" id="theValue" name="type1Value" value="Option A"/>
```

2.-add onChange function to your select, which changes previous hidden value

```
<select id="type1" name="type1" onChange="updateValue()">
   <option value="1">Option A</option>
   <option value="2">Option B</option>
</select>
```

assuming you are using jQuery:

```
function updateValue(){
   var value= $('#type1').find(":selected").text();
   $('#theValue').val(value);
}
```

so the value of the select will be sent in type1Value variable, EASY!!

Answer (score 0):

using React js

I want to get two values from the option at the same time
so, I use the Split method

```
var string = "0,1";
var array = string.split(",");
alert(array[0]);
```

I create a sting on option

```
const getKioskSelectedUsageType=(e)=>{
  let sl = e.target.value 
  let array = sl.split(",")
  console.log("check :- ",array[1] )

}

         <select
          id=""
          className="form-control"
          value={kioskSelect}
          aria-label="kioskSelect"
          name="kioskSelect"
          title="kioskSelect"
          onChange={(e) => getKioskSelectedUsageType(e)}
          style={{ color: "#495057" }}
          >

          <option value="">Select Kiosk</option>
          {kioskConfiData.map((item, i) => {
           return (
           <React.Fragment key={i}>
           
           <option value={`${item.kioskid},${item.language}`}>
                  {item.location}
         </option>
         </React.Fragment>
         );
         })}
         </select>
```